# Get all columns from a SqlAlchemy table to filter on them

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I build default equal filters for all columns of the table and then add/override only specific filters I want on a few columns, like this:

```
# Table definition

class OrderTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"

    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

# Build all default filters for this table

table_filters = {column.name: lambda value: column == value for column in OrderTable.__table__.columns}

# Add/override specific filters

all_filters = {**table_filters, "name": lambda value: OrderTable.name.like(value)}

# Execute the query

query = ...
query = query.filter(all_filters["id"](123)) 
query.delete()
```

But I get this warning when using default filters:

```
SAWarning: Evaluating non-mapped column expression 'orders.id' onto ORM instances; this is a deprecated use case.  Please make use of the actual mapped columns in ORM-evaluated UPDATE / DELETE expressions.
```

Is there a better way to get all columns to be able to filter on them without getting this warning?

I tried different ways of gettings all columns for a table with `OrderTable.__mapper__.attrs` and `inspect(OrderTable).attrs` but then the filters do not work.

I am not used to post so please tell me if I can improve my question and I will edit it.

Comment: Why do you want such a convoluted way to get and apply filters ? Also if it helps, this warning was added as part of [`db170dd4`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/db170dd4529c5176d38db649dd75427a932b47fe), from before version 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I want to separate the domain logic from the implementation logic so I don't want to have imports to sqlalchemy higher in the code, I also want to be able to have a different name for a filter at the API level without impacting the filters on the table.

Comment: That sounds convoluted and hard to maintain, maybe take a step back and consider the filtering problem you're trying to solve. Feel free to explain it here and we can discuss it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to explain it as well as I can. Let's say I have a model on the Rest API `OrderJSON` that has properties `id` and `label`. I want to decouple my Rest API from my ORM so I want to be able to map `label` to `name`. If I get a filter on `label`, I want to translate it to a filter on `name` of `OrderTable`. I want to decouple the Rest API from the database schemas to help with maintenance and isolation. Is there a better way to do that than with a dict on columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to fetching columns from the table vs using attributes directly.

When you use the attibute directly, you get an `InstrumentedAttribute`, when you get the column from `__table__.columns` you get a `Column`.

With the `Column` you get that warning:

```py
id_filter_col = OrderTable.__table__.c["id"] == 1

query = session.query(OrderTable)
query = query.filter(id_filter_col)
query.delete()  # SAWarning: Evaluating non-mapped column expression 'orders.id' onto ORM instances...
```

But now when you use the `InstrumentedAttribute`:

```py
id_filter_attr = OrderTable.id == 2

query = session.query(OrderTable)
query = query.filter(id_filter_attr)
query.delete()  # OK
```

You can access the attributes from the mapper via `__mapper__.all_orm_descriptors`, which should solve your problem.

```py
class OrderTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"

    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

table_filters = {column.key: lambda value: column == value for column in OrderTable.__mapper__.all_orm_descriptors}

all_filters = {**table_filters, "name": lambda value: OrderTable.name.like(value)}

query = ...
query = query.filter(all_filters["id"](123)) 
query.delete()  # OK
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just had to change `column.name` with `column.key` for `InstrumentedAttribute`

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'll do the change in my post as well.